# Programming a bot in Discord- How do I make the bot send a random image from a subreddit?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my bot send a random image from a subreddit (r/memes). Here's what I have:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('.meme'):
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 50)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

    await bot.say(submission.url)
```

It doesn't seem to be working, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bot.say` was removed in discord.py 1.0 and replaced with `.send`.

So the line `await bot.say(submission.url)` should be replaced with
`await message.channel.send(submission.url)`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=say#removed-helpers

In your for loop you recreate the list of non-sticked post each time and then call next but because you recreate it will always return first element of recreated list. You should move the `x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied` out of the loop into a varible. You could then user `next` but easier would be just to index that variable like it is a list with the random number.